# Draw triangle's in pygame given only side lengths

Tags: python, math, pygame

I have three line lengths and I need to plot a triangle on the screen with them.
Say I have:

```
len1 = 30
len2 = 50
len3 = 70
(these are randomly generated)
```

I can draw the first line at the bottom like this

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, red, (500,500), (500+len1,500), 10)
```

The other two lines will start at (500,500) and (500+len1,500) respectivly and will have the same endpoint but I can't figure out the math to get that location

Comment: This isn't a programming task but more a mathematical problem. I did the search work for you and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known) is the answer. Rest is up to you, to write the code for it

Comment: @Bazingaa Did't see that when I searched, thanks.

Comment: To get the angles from the side lengths you need the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), if a, b, c are the side lengths then the cosine of A, the angle between b and c is. `cosine A = (b^2+c^2-a^2)/(2 b c)`.

Answer (score 0):

Converted the formula in Jody Muelaner's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known) to python:

```
def thirdpoint(a, b, c):
    result = []
    y=((a**2)+(b**2)-(c**2))/(a*2)
    x = math.sqrt((b**2)-(y**2))
    result.append(x)
    result.append(y)
    return result
```